# JSONArray to Listview what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

Hello guys i have now searched for the error or how to do it correct for some time and yes alot of questions in here have helped me closer i think.

but i got an API where i get a JSONArray and i want to show this data in a listview. So far i get my data in my log, and now i just try to show the name from each object to start with(then i can add the rest of data later) but im not sure if im on the right spot maybe someone can help me out here and show what im doing wrong?

Thanks alot

Listview name: AllBirds

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_observation);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String URL="myAPI";

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e("Rest Response",response.toString());

            try{
                for(int i=0; i<response.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String NameDanish = jresponse.getString("NameDanish");

                    Log.d("NameDanish", NameDanish);


                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Rest Response",error.toString());
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_all_observation, NameDanish);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AllBirds);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what is **`NameDanish`** here

Comment: Can you paste the JSONArray response as well

Comment: past your json response

Comment: You can pass the String value (NameDanish) in ArrayAdapter. PLease pass String array or Arraylist in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: i have added all the code in the bottom as a question. i tryed to debug på code and i get nothing in my arraylist, but i still see all the names in my log.

Answer (score 1):

Create ArrayList in your class

ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

change your above code with

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_observation);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        String URL = "myAPI";

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.e("Rest Response", response.toString());

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String NameDanish = jresponse.getString("NameDanish");
                        arrayList.add(NameDanish);
                        Log.d("NameDanish", NameDanish);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Rest Response", error.toString());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_all_observation, arrayList);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AllBirds);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry posted my comment longer down, take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a string arraylist globally like this

```
ArrayList<String> name_array=new ArrayList<>();
```

then add

```
         try{
            for(int i=0; i<response.length();i++){
                JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String NameDanish = jresponse.getString("NameDanish");
                name_array.add(NameDanish);
                Log.d("NameDanish", NameDanish);
            }
```

then pass this arraylist to your adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_all_observation, name_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create listView, adapter, array as member variable and use notifyDataUpdate from responseHandler to update data.

```
    ListView mList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter
    ArrayList<String> mData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_observation);
        mData=new ArrayList<>();

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AllBirds);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_all_observation, mData);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        String URL="myAPI";

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.e("Rest Response",response.toString());

                try{
                    for(int i=0; i<response.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        String NameDanish = jresponse.getString("NameDanish");
                        mData.add(NameDanish);
                        Log.d("NameDanish", NameDanish);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Rest Response",error.toString());
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now changed the code to this as Toyj said, i have posted my xml to.

i dont get any data out only all the names are showed in the log?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_observation);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    final ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<>()

    String URL="MYAPI";

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest (Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e("Rest Response",response.toString());

            try{
                //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i=0; i<response.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String NameDanish = jresponse.getString("NameDanish");
                    arrayList.add(NameDanish);
                    Log.d("NameDanish", NameDanish);


                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Rest Response",error.toString());
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_all_observation, arrayList);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AllBirds);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**JSON data looks like this where i just take NameDanish to start with**

```
    {
    "BirdId": 1,
    "Comment": null,
    "Created": "/Date(1523836800000+0000)/",
    "Id": 132,
    "Latitude": 55.6886037,
    "Longitude": 12.5310135,
    "Placename": "K",
    "Population": 0,
    "UserId": "user1",
    "NameDanish": "solsort",
    "NameEnglish": "blackbird"
}
```

**XML file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.all_observationActivity">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AllBirds">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```